# True global minima of 6 parameter rational function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find the value and positions of the global minima of a 6 parameter rational function. My current try is something like

```
NMinimize[{function[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6], region}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}]
```

Which gives me one result with which there are two problems:

(1) The presented point is possibly not the only global minimum. How can I get all of them if there is more than one? (I have seen equivalent questions here, but the most important question is the following:)

(2) If I set and change a starting interval for one or more parameters in the search, i.e.

```
NMinimize[{function[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6], region}, {{x1, x1i, x1f}, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}]
```

the value of the minimum changes, which obviously means that earlier presented greater values were not global minima at all.

How can I solve this and what is the problem?

Comment: From the documentation: If your function and the constraints are linear, NMinimize will find *global* minima. Otherwise, NMinimize may sometimes find only a local minimum. Unforutnately you do not share the function or the constraints, so my guess would be that your function is not linear and you were returned a local minimum the first time. Finding a guaranteed global minimum of an arbitrary function is hard.

Comment: Does `Minimize[]` solve your problem?

Comment: Try to use **Method->"DifferentialEvolution"**

Comment: @MarcoB My function is a ratio of multiple variables polynomials. I see! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Unfortunately it does not seem like my problem would have an analytical solution.

Comment: @Cesareo I will try! Thank you.